# What is the difference between a measure being "supported on [set] $A$" vs "supported in $A$" vs "supported at $A$"?

Tags: measure-theory, terminology

What is the difference between saying three things (here $A$ is a set)

> (1) Let $\mu$ be a measure supported on $A$

and

> (2) Let $\mu$ be a measure supported in $A$

and

> (3) Let $\mu$ be a measure supported at $A$

I believe that (1) and (3) mean the same thing, which I think could be written for short as $\operatorname{supp} \mu= A$. If this is the case, then I think (2) would mean that $\operatorname{supp} \mu\subseteq A$.

But still, I feel like my understanding is not completely correct. I could not find any definition in books/websites of what saying "supported $\dots$" means.

Please enlighten me. Thank you